# Highlight changes in a specific entry of a reference list created with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, color, highlighting, changes

I would like to highlight changes in a specific entry (or even a part of the entry) of a reference list created with biblatex, e.g., by changing the font color to red. (Unfortunately such a feature is not available in [todonotes](http://ctan.org/pkg/todonotes).)

Apart from [the conversation here](http://compgroups.net/comp.text.tex/-biblatex-conditionnal-output-format/214239), I couldn't find anything helpful. Two examples are given there, but I was not able to run them correctly.

**Example 1**

```
%For example, if you want to print the title of recent entries in red,
%you'd modify the "title" format:

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{color}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{%
\usebibmacro{color_recent}{\mkbibemph{#1}}}
\newbibmacro{color_recent}[1]{%
\iffieldint{year}
{\ifnumgreater{\thefield{year}}{1999}
{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
{#1}}
{#1}}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

**Example 2**

```
%If you want the complete entry in red, it's easier to use a hook like
%\AtEveryBibitem:

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{color}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\AtEveryBibitem{%
\iffieldint{year}
{\ifnumgreater{\thefield{year}}{1999}
{\color{red}}
{}}
{}}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

**My error**

For both examples I get:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> Przepi\x 
                    {fffd}\x {fffd}rka
l.19 \end
         {document}
?
```

Comment: Both examples works well. I think you should update your system.

Comment: Judging from your error message, it seems to be an encoding problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm working with pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011) on Debian Squeeze and I updates all packages. The input file is encoded in UTF-8, I use nothing else. Am I missing something?

Comment: @deboerk: Use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

Comment: Now it's working. Thanks very much! How can I mark this question as solved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the comments I provide an answer.

The error occurs by an encoding problem. To avoid this you can load the package `inputenc` with your used encoding. Normally the encoding is `utf8`.

So add to your preamble:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```