# Undefined control sequence<to be read again> with biblatex and Zotero

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, texmaker, zotero

I am using Texmaker 4.0.4 and exported my `biblatex.bib` from Zotero. 
My file `test.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{Biblatex.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{campbell2007}
\cite{moffitt86}

\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

My `biblatex.bib`:

```
@article{moffitt86,
    title = {The econometrics of piecewise-linear budget constraints: a survey and exposition of the maximum likelihood method},
    shorttitle = {The econometrics of piecewise-linear budget constraints},
    pages = {317–328},
    journaltitle = {Journal of Business \& Economic Statistics},
    author = {Moffitt, R.},
    date = {1986},
    file = {Google Scholar Linked Page:files/837/Moffitt - 1986 - The econometrics of piecewise-linear budget constr:}
}


@article{campbell2007,
    title = {"Says who" How the source of price information and affect influence perceived price (un) fairness},
    volume = {44},
    issue = {2},
    pages = {261-271},
    journaltitle = {Journal of Marketing Research},
    author = {Campbell, {M.C.}},
    date = {2007},
    file = {Google Scholar Linked Page:files/912/jmkr.44.2.html:text/html}
}
```

I am getting an error message with:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<to be read again> \edef \blx@tempa {317\x
{FFFD}\x {FFFD}\x {FFFD}328}
l.11 \end
{document}
```

Any idea about how can I solve this problem?

Comment: This happens when you have "strange characters" in your reference. For example, your pages in reference `moffitt86` are `317–328` when it should be `317-328` (different dash). [Search for `fffd` on this site](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=fffd)) and you'll see similar problems and how they're fixed. All you have to do is replace the faulty hyphen `–` with `-`.

Comment: This is indeed the case. It should be some bug when exporting the file from Zotero. I will do a find and replace through the biblatex.bib. I'm now having another problem with using a different style but I will do another question. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that this is *not* a Zotero bug, though. You have set the Zotero export charset to `utf-8` and an en-dash is a valid `utf-8` character.

You can solve this without search & replace by either using `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`
as e.g. per [Highlight changes in a specific entry of a reference list created with `biblatex`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52441/31980).

Alternatively, you can set the export charset in Zotero to `ISO 8859-1`, which will escape en-dashes as `{\textendash}` (the latter option is not available in the `biblatex` export from Zotero, only in BibTeX)

Comment: Thanks. The use of `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` solved the issue smoothly.